# How to show jquery DataTable column as Custom Javascript action link

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using the below code to generate the table, but I need to show **code** as link where I should able to run custom code to navigate to another record

```js
$('#customerdt').DataTable({
  "bInfo": false,
  data: accountData,
  columns: [
    { data: 'code' },
    { data: 'customerid' },
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'telephone' },
    { data: 'emailaddress' },
    { data: 'joiningdate' }
  ],
  "bDestroy": true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option

```js
const table = $('#customerdt').DataTable({
  "bInfo": false,
  data: accountData,
  columns: [
    {
        data: 'code',
        render: (data, type, row) => `<a href="#" class="my-class" data-email="${row.emailaddress}">${data}</a>`
    }
    { data: 'customerid' },
    { data: 'name' },
    { data: 'telephone' },
    { data: 'emailaddress' },
    { data: 'joiningdate' }
  ],
  "bDestroy": true
});

table.on('click', '.my-class', function() {
    const emailAddress = this.getAttribute('data-email');
}
```

Comment: I need to call another js function bypassing other column Email Address

Comment: @SriKanth I edited my answer. I've assigned the datatable to a variable, given the link a class and a `data-email` attribute with the email address. Then I created an event listener on the table to listen for the link's class and get the link's email address attribute.